# Send Automatically teams meeting calendar spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I've seen that is possible to send automatically Outlook mails with SpringBoot and the specific component. It's possible to send Outlook or other types mails with a Teams meeting inside?

For example the sent mail will have, on above, the following text:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlxWz.jpg)

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Your question does not seem related to Teams app development. Could you please elaborate a little on your query?

Answer (score 0):

That would basically be sending invitations, right?

Then you have to take a look at the Microsoft Graph API. It is used for all kinds of purposes and one part is dedicated to [Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-concept-overview).

One example that I found by quickly googling is [Creating an Online Meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).